# Proof that If $f:X\to Y$ is surjective and $X$ is finite, then $Y$ is finite without AC

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I try to prove the following exercise without using the axiom of choice. On the second item, the proof that I found in the books, to define the function $g:Y\to X$, for every $y\in Y$, due to the surjective of $f$ they **choose** $x=g(y)\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Let $f:X\to Y$, prove.

1. If $Y$ is finite and $f$ injective, then $X$ is finite.
2. If $X$ is finite and $f$ surjective, then $Y$ is finite.

**Proof:**

1. Done.
2. Let $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. Given any $y\in Y$, because $f$ is surjective, then exists $k\in I_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $y=f(x_k)$. Consider the set
   $$A_y:=\{i\in I_n:f(x_i)=y\}$$

   Then $A_y\neq\emptyset$ because $k\in A$, so, by the Well-ordering principle, $A_y$ has a minimal element, let this element $i_y$, then $$f(x_{i_y})=y.$$

   Define $g:Y\to X$ by $g(y):=x_{i_y}$. Im particular we get
   $$f(g(y))=f(x_{i_y})=y,\quad \forall y\in Y.$$

Prove that $g$ is injective. Let $y,z\in Y$ such that $g(y)=g(z)$, then 
    $$g(y)=g(z)\Longrightarrow f(g(y))=f(g(z)) \Longrightarrow  y=z.$$

Therefore, $g$ is injective, then by the first item, $Y$ is finite.

Is it right?

Comment: You can not say: let $Y=\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}$, since you do not know whether $Y$ is finite yet. Otherwise, is fine.

Comment: Of course you mean $A_y=\{i\in I_n:f(x_i)=y\}$ and $k\in A_y$ instead of $x_k\in A$

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis you are right,i forgot to erase it.

Comment: @PeterMelech you are right, I edited it!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your proof is fine. Although it is in fact a bit complicated.

If you have proved that if $X$ is finite, then $\mathcal P(X)$ is finite, then you can just appeal to this, as $y\mapsto f^{-1}(y)$ is an injection from $Y$ into $\mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very nice and simple answer. But acording to the material covered, it has not proven yet that if $X$ is finte then $P(X)$ is finite(it is an exercise at the end of the section), having done this, i can use this as a second solution

Comment: Yes, note that the fact about power sets is entirely independent of the statement you're trying to prove here. So there will be no circularity.

Comment: Note that the OP is essentially proving that every if $X$ is any finite set then any partition $\rho$ of $X$ if finite (only a finite number of blocks). And of course $\rho \subset \mathcal P(X)$. Just saying...

Comment: @CopyPasteIt: Yes, this is the alternative proof I've suggested. You're right that this is equivalent. Nevertheless, partitions tend to be significantly smaller compared to the power set (e.g. any partition of a countable set is countable).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. The reason you do not need choice is because you have a well-order on $X$ (which exists without choice because $X$ is finite). So you can do essentially the same argument as at the top of your post, "...*choose* $x$ such that $f(x) = y$...", only now "choose" does not invoke choice because of the well-order on $X$.

In fact, your proof generalises to the following statement. If $X$ has a well-order and $f: X \to Y$ is surjective, then there is a section $g: Y \to X$ (i.e. injective $g$, s.t. $fg$ is the identity).

Answer (score 0):

You do it very complicated. Suppose $|Y|=|X|+1$. Since it's surjective, if $y\in Y$, there is $x\in X$ s.t. $y=f(x)$. But then, $|X|$ element will have $|X|+1$ images, which is impossible (an element can not have several images). Therefore $|Y|\leq |X|$.

Comment: While not essentially wrong, there is a case to argue this answer is misleading without additional information. Some of the times we *prove* that the cardinals behave the way they should by arguing first about injections and surjections and all of that. So making the appeal to size consideration is now circular. Without knowing the exact context in which the question is framed, it's hard to say, though.

Comment: We can wait until the OP clarifies...

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you, the context is a course on introduction to real analysis, finite and infinite sets, i am no using cardinals numbers, just cardinal as the number of elements of a set.